# Are array memory addresses always in the order of least to greatest?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When I'm making a procedure with pointer arithmetic and `!=`, such as

```
template <typename T> void reverse_array ( T * arr, size_t n )
{
    T * end = arr + n; 
    while (arr != end && arr != --end) 
    {
         swap(arr,end);
         ++arr;
    }
}
```

I always take a lot of caution because if I write my procedure wrong then in a corner case the first pointer might "jump over" the second one. But, if arrays are such that

```
&arr[0] < &arr[1] < ... < &arr[n]
```

for any array `arr` of length `n-1`, then can't I just do something like

```
template <typename T> void reverse_array ( T * arr, size_t n )
{
    T * end = arr + n;
    if (arr == end) break;
    --end;
    while (arr < end)
    {
        swap(arr,end);
        ++arr; --end;
    }
}
```

since it's more readable? Or is there a danger looming? Aren't memory addresses just integral types and thus comparable with `<` ?

Comment: I suggest that you execute `--end` somewhere else, and not as part of the stop-condition of the `while` statement. It will make your code more readable, and will help avoiding doubts as to the value of `end` within that condition as well as inside the loop itself. If you really need to test both conditions in the statement, then use `end-1` (and decrement it **inside** the loop).

Comment: Yes it works. I don't know what `n` is supposed to be, but if you want the next element you better use +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relational operators are defined to work correctly when comparing addresses within the same array (in fact, also objects of class type, where there are some guarantees about memory layout also) including the one-past-the-end pointer.

However, if you "jump over" the end-of-array pointer, you are no longer comparing two addresses within the same array, and the behavior is undefined.  (One cause is that you might in fact experience wraparound when you do pointer arithmetic outside objects, but UB is not restricted).

Your case is perfectly fine concerning jump-over, because your `end` pointer isn't the one-past-the-end of the array, since you always do at least one `--end`.  An empty array, where `--end` moves outside the array, would be an issue, but you test for that separately.

Conclusion: your second code is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

For C (since you tagged both), yes, they can be compared, within the same array:

> When two  pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to.  If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal.   If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values.  All  pointers to members of the same union object compare equal.   If the
>   expression `P` points to an element of an array object and the expression `Q` points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression `Q+1` compares greater than `P`. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

-- C11 6.5.8, "Relational operators".

But it's not because they're "just integral types", which they aren't (and [aren't guaranteed to be represented as in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578480/1366431)) - it's because they also have the behaviour defined for them.